# Multiple Interfaces having same implementation - Duplicate Symbol Error- Objective - c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, duplicate-symbol

I was working on a static library with an NSObject class named 
    'ClientRequest'

I had to import the NSObject of type ClientRequest to my other classes: A, B and C.

So all the above mentioned classes implements like below

```
#import "ClientRequest.h"

@interface A : ClientRequest

#import "ClientRequest.h"

@interface B : ClientRequest

#import "ClientRequest.h"

@interface C : ClientRequest
```

The static library project(.xcodeproj) was added to the my own project and the target included with the static libary. 
When I ran my own project, I had the 'duplicate symbol _API_BASE_ for i386 architecture' error for the A  and B, A and C & A and ClientRequest.

Any Idea how to tackle this problem? The Classes A, B and C uses the methods of ClientRequest.

Comment: How do you import the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you are doing is hard to determine without additional information. However from what is given it appears that you are defining `API_BASE` in the `ClientRequest.h` file so that in every file you include a new item is defined and you end up with multiple items.

One way this can occur is if you define a global variable incorrectly.

If you declare a global variable in `ClientRequest.h` as, say:

```
int API_BASE;
```

then *every* file compiled which includes the header will define its own copy of that variable and you'll get duplicate symbol errors. The correct way to do it is to *declare* the variable as `extern in the header:

```
extern int API_BASE;
```

and to define it once in `ClientRequest.m`:

```
int API_BASE;
```

The `extern` keyword indicates that you are declaring the name and type of a variable which will be defined elsewhere.

All function/methods declaration are implicitly external, but the keyword is required for variables.

HTH